# Google App Script: Share spreadsheets in Column 1, with Users in Column 2

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

##### Objective

On script run, give view access for all of the emails (column B), to all of the spreadsheets (column A)

##### The Spreadsheet looks like:

| Sheet URL's | Emails |
| --- | --- |
| https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1 | Bob@email.com |
| https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/2 | John@email.com |

##### The script

```
function setSheetPermissions(){
  //Spreadsheet that contains the Spreadsheet URL's & Emails.
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetID')
  
  // Sheet name that contains the URL's & Emails
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  
  // Get the values of all the URL's in column A
  var getSheetURLs = sheet.getRange("A2:A50").getValues();

  // Get the values of all the emails in column B
  var getEmails = sheet.getRange("B2:B50").getValues();
  
  for ( i in getEmails)
     getSheetURLs.addViewer(getEmails[i][0])

}
```

##### Problem / Error

> getSheetIDs.addViewer is not a function (line 26, file "Code")

Line 26: `getSheetURLs.addViewer(getEmails[i][0])`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- You can retrieve both values from the columns "A" and "B".
- In your script, `getSheetURLs` is a 2 dimensional array. In this case, the method `addViewer` cannot be directly used. I thought that this is the reason for your error message.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
// Get the values of all the URL's in column A
var getSheetURLs = sheet.getRange("A2:A50").getValues();

// Get the values of all the emails in column B
var getEmails = sheet.getRange("B2:B50").getValues();

for ( i in getEmails)
   getSheetURLs.addViewer(getEmails[i][0])
```

##### To:

```
var values = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
values.forEach(([sheetUrl, email]) => {
  if (sheetUrl && email) SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl + "/edit").addViewer(email);
});
```

- From your showing sample Spreadsheet, I understood that your Spreadsheet URL is like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###`. In this case, `openByUrl` cannot be directly used. So I added `/edit`. If your showing Spreadsheet URLs are different from your sample Spreadsheet, please provide your sample Spreadsheet URL. By this, I would like to modify the script.
- If your actual Spreadsheet URLs are both `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###` and `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit`, you can also use `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl + (sheetUrl.includes("/edit") ? "" : "/edit")).addViewer(email)`.

#### References:

- [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)
- [addViewer(emailAddress) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addvieweremailaddress)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you Tanaike! I learned so much from your modifications. They are working perfectly. To answer your question about the URL's, some have /edit, some do not. So I used `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl + (sheetUrl.includes("/edit") ? "" : "/edit")).addViewer(email)`. You do amazing work! :)